# How to read text file in JADE

Tags: user-interface, file, agents, agents-jade

I am stuck in putting the Jave text file read code in JADE GUI. Please assist.I.e. Show using a simple code. I am new to Jade but experienced in Java coding.

Comment: Are you doing the JADE examples? Exactly what GUI are you talking about in JADE?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about OODB Jade?

Have you considered checking out the forums or wiki (wiki.jadeworld.com)? Code samples exist for such things.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the same as for any Java application. It worked for me when I tried File operations. Your error could be in:

1. Improper interfacing between GUI and commands
2. OR error in Java File commands

It would be helpful if you could provide a few code snippets